# como parar o loop do for em uma determina ação?

Tags: php, html, mysql

bom pessoal tenho um problema tenho um formulario que faz o uploads de fotos e salva o nome no banco de dados e move os arquivo para pasta especificada o problema esta que o loop sempre se repete 5 vezes se eu insiro 5 fotos tudo ocorre normal as fotos são salvas no banco e movidas para pasta mais se envio 1 foto da um erro dizendo

> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in

Mais se envio 2 da um erro

> Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in

Mais se envio 3 da um erro

> Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in

Mais se envio 5 não da nenhum erro

mais as fotos sao movidas para pasta e no banco e salvo o nome mais adiciona 5 linhas por exemplo se envio uma foto so ela e movida para pasta mais no banco e solvo 5 linhas 4 ficam vazias e uma com o nome da foto que enviei

```
 <form  action="recebe_form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <label class="label">
        <span class="legend">fotos adicionais</span>        
            <input type="file" name="fotos[]" multiple/>
      </label>
 </form>
```

```html
<?php 

 include_once("/../../../_app/config.inc.php");
 // Pasta de destino das fotos 

$Destino = "../../../../img_uploads/windows/1/"; 
 // Obtém dados do upload 
$Fotos = $_FILES["fotos"]; 
// Contagem de fotos enviadas 
$Conta = 0; 

 // Itera sobre as enviadas e processa as validações e upload 
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($Fotos); $i++) 
{ 
 // Passa valores da iteração atual 
$Nome = $Fotos["name"][$i]; 
$Tamanho = $Fotos["size"][$i]; 
$Tipo = $Fotos["type"][$i]; 
$Tmpname = $Fotos["tmp_name"][$i]; 

// Verifica se tem arquivo enviado 
if($Tamanho > 0 && strlen($Nome) > 1) 
{ 
 // Verifica se é uma imagem 
if(preg_match("/^image\/(gif|jpeg|jpg|png)$/", $Tipo)) 
{ 
// Caminho completo de destino da foto 
$Caminho = $Destino . $Nome; 

 // Tudo OK! Move o upload! 
move_uploaded_file($Tmpname, $Caminho);

}
} $query = $pdo->query("INSERT INTO so_windows_gallery SET image ='$Nome', id_ = 1 "); 
}
```

```html
array (size=5)
  'name' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '17172939023126.jpg' (length=18)
  'type' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
  'tmp_name' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'C:\wamp64\tmp\phpBA42.tmp' (length=25)
  'error' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 0
  'size' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 194677
```

Comment: Faça a modificação que eu falei na minha resposta e você não precisará parar o loop. Seu código está simplesmente contando o número de elementos do array errado.

Comment: vou tenta aqui arruma ve se da certo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize um `var_dump($Fotos);` abaixo da declaração da variável e verás o porque seu loop não está funcionando. $_FILES retorna um array associativo contendo um array indexado para cada associação.

Troque `sizeof($Fotos)` por `sizeof($Fotos['name'])`. Para evitar confusões com `sizeOf()` em outras linguagens eu sugiro que utilize `count()` que faz a mesma coisa.

Respondendo a pergunta do título: você pode parar um loop utilizando um `break;` ou até mesmo um simples `return;`

Comment: fiz como voce dize e funcionou certinho salvo minha vida